# Dependency Injection Autofac UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am getting the following error on the **set** part of

```
public IUnitOfWork uoW { get; set; }
```

in the below class

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        public IUnitOfWork uoW { get; set; }


        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
                uoW.BeginTransaction();
        }

        protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
                uoW.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: controllerContext]
   System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +30

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) +61
   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) +21
   Autofac.Core.DefaultPropertySelector.InjectProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Object instance) +111
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringPropertyInjector.InjectProperties(IComponentContext context, Object instance, IPropertySelector propertySelector) +437
   Autofac.Builder.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<PropertiesAutowired>b__1(Object s, ActivatingEventArgs`1 e) +24
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.RaiseActivating(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +73
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +255
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +131
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +133
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +44

[DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +112
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +108
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +74
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +54
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) +67
   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +41

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Juniper.Web.Controllers.RoleController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +194
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

DependencyConfig Looks like below in DependencyConfig.cs

```
private static void BuildApplicationDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            Assembly mvcApplicationAssembly = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly;

            // AutoMapper
            var autoMapperProfileTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(p => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsPublic && !p.IsAbstract));
            var autoMapperProfiles = autoMapperProfileTypes.Select(p => (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(p));
            builder.Register(ctx => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                foreach (var profile in autoMapperProfiles)
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(profile);
                }
            }));

            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
   .As(typeof(IRepository<>));
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
       .PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterType<RoleService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
            builder.Register(container => new RoleController(container.Resolve<IRoleService>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.Register(container => new UserController(container.Resolve<IRoleService>(), container.Resolve<IUserService>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // register the filter provider which automatically enables property injection on action filters
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

            // Needed to allow property injection in custom action filters.
            builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>().InstancePerRequest();

            // register the controllers (injecting the action invoker)
            builder.RegisterControllers(mvcApplicationAssembly).InjectActionInvoker().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.PreserveSetValues);

            builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
        }
```

UnitOfWork.cs:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private ITransaction _transaction;

        public ISession Session { get; set; }

        static UnitOfWork()
        {
            _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ABCD")))
               .Mappings(m =>
                         m.FluentMappings
                         .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public void BeginTransaction()
        {
            _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                    _transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                    _transaction.Rollback();

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Session.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_transaction != null && _transaction.IsActive)
                    _transaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                Session.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , please find UnitOfWork.cs class implementing IUnitOfWork

Comment: remove PropertyWiringOptions.PreserveSetValues   from         builder.RegisterControllers(mvcApplicationAssembly).InjectActionInvoker().PropertiesAutowired(); for more info please find [this](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/33ED0D92.htm) link hope it'll work

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with the "unit of work" pattern and everything to do with how you register and resolve stuff. Perhaps a better question title is in order?